# Post html form to php to rest api

Tags: php, forms, post

I am trying to post a form to a php file but the php doest seem to be able to read the post data. Noob here, what am I doing wrong

Html Form

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Voucher Generator</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="view.css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="view.js"></script>

</head>
<body id="main_body" >

<img id="top" src="top.png" alt="">
<div id="form_container">

<h1><a>Voucher Generator</a></h1>
<form id="form_71867" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="post.php">
<div class="form_description">
<h2>Voucher Generator</h2>
<p></p>
</div>                      
<ul >

<li id="li_1" >
<label class="description" for="element_1">Mobile </label>
<div>
<input id="element_1" name="simu" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
</div> 
</li>       <li id="li_2" >
<label class="description" for="element_2">Package Amount </label>
<div>
<input id="element_2" name="pesa" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
</div> 
</li>

<li class="buttons">
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="71867" />

<input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</li>
</ul>
</form> 
<div id="footer">
Generated by <a href="http://www.phpform.org">pForm</a>
</div>
</div>
<img id="bottom" src="bottom.png" alt="">
</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php
//POST DATA
$mobile = $_POST['simu'];
$amount = $_POST['pesa'];
//API Url
$url = 'http://localhost:8080/k2/ipn.php';

//Initiate cURL.
$ch = curl_init($url);

//The JSON data.
$jsonData = array(
    'sender_phone' =>  $mobile,
    'amount' =>  $amount
);

//Encode the array into JSON.
$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);

//Tell cURL that we want to send a POST request.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//Attach our encoded JSON string to the POST fields.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);

//Set the content type to application/json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json')); 

//Execute the request
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

The php file is posting  "$mobile" & "$amount" to the endpoint instead of the actual values. 
The whole process is actually;
-  a user fills the html form which send the data to the php file 
- php file converts it to json and post to the api endpoint.

I can't find any information on posting json from a form directly

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST);` output ?

Comment: _“The php file is posting "$mobile" & "$amount" to the endpoint instead of the actual values”_ - that is quite hard to imagine with the code you have shown; my guess would be that you might have used those variable names inside a single-quoted string somewhere ...

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP code is correctly encoding the values into JSON, therefore the problem you experience must come from the client-side. You will need to check that:

- the parameters you are expecting are actually sent with the very same name
- simu and pesa, respectively hold only the values and not names, like $mobile or $amount
- your real code is very similar to the code you have shown in this question, I am particularly interested about the things you could have between quotes

If the content of this answer does not solve your question, then make sure you edit your question and give us some details about the request sent to the server on post.